# Critical Point System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation: 
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2a(x^2-1)\frac{dx}{dt}+kx=0.$$
How can I find the critical point(s)? I know that must set the derivative equal to $0$. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to rewrite this as a system of first-order equations in $x,y=x'$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x'=y$ then you have an equivalent system of $$y'= -2a(x^2-1)y - kx \space\space\space\space (1)$$ $$x'=y \space\space\space\space\space (2)$$The critical point(s) occur where $x'= y'=0$. We see that this happens at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat the equivalent system of first-order equations in $x,x'$ our critical points will occur where $x'=x''=0$ so $kx=0$, yielding $x=0$.